# VBA Deleting blank worksheets where the worksheets have been renamed in Spanish?

Tags: vba

I am working with a file where the worksheets have been renamed. Instead of Sheet1(generic name) it is Hoja1(generic name).

Wondering if this is stopping my code from working.

My code is very simple. I dont know what other error I could be having.

---

```
Sub  Macro1()

Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

Application.DisplaysAlerts = False
If LenB(ActiveSheet.Range("A5")) = "" Then ActiveSheet.Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Next ws

End Sub
```

---

Thank you.

Comment: what is that function supposed to do? It looks to me like you should get a type mismatch error

Answer (score 0):

If it's definitely going to have "Hoja" in the sheet name, this should work.

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim WS As Worksheet

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

For Each WS In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets

    If InStr(WS.Name, "Hoja") <> 0 Then WS.Delete

Next

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work :c

I don't think saying that the worksheets have been renamed is the correct way to explain this. Sorry, I am very new with VBA.

The tabs are named 1,2,3,4,5... etc.

It is when I open VBA and look at the Microsoft Excel Objects that I see that the sheets are named Hoja24(1), Hoja25(3), ... etc.

This is different than when I open a file of my own. Where the objects are named Sheet1(somename).

Answer (score 0):

Got some help from someone.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

Application.DisplayAlerts = False 
If LenB(ws.Range"A5")) = 0 Then ws.Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Next ws
```

The spanish wasn't the issue.

Comment: Just to clarify, your goal is to delete all sheets where cell A5 is empty, no matter what the other cells contain?

Comment: Yup.

I was working with some messy files. It was the case sometimes that A5 was clear even though the rest of the sheet was full with data. I made something to go through the worksheets and delete all the completely empty rows. That way all the data would rise to the top. Cells A1-A4 were part of a header. I chose A5 because, after the row clearing, it would correctly indicate if the rest of the spreadsheet had info or not. 

Any suggestions on how to do this better are welcomed o:

Answer (score 0):

To get the name `Hoja1` if the sheet appears as `Hoja1(1)` in the VBA browser you can use the `.CodeName` property:

```
'code borrowed from Alex's answer
Sub Macro1()

Dim WS As Worksheet

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

For Each WS In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets

    If InStr(WS.CodeName, "Hoja") <> 0 Then WS.Delete

Next

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```